# Login Button on my React Auth Component Won't Work on Mobile

Tags: reactjs, authentication, mobile, react-redux

I have a React/Node app with authentication using JWT. It works on desktop, but when I click on the login button on mobile (Android Pixel 2) nothing happens.
Here is the Auth component:

I've tried it on a physical mobile, and using an emulator. Doesn't work on either. It's on a Node/Express server which is running on localhost.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {authUser, logout} from '../store/actions';

class Auth extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleOnSubmit = this.handleOnSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}

handleOnSubmit(e) {
    const {username, password} = this.state;
    const {authType} = this.props;
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.authUser(authType || 'login', {username, password});
}


    render()
    {
        const {username, password} = this.state;

        return <div>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
                <label className="form-label" htmlFor="username">username</label>
                <input className="form-input" 
                type="text" 
                value={username} 
                name="username" 
                autoComplete="off"
                onChange={this.handleChange} />

                <label className="form-label" htmlFor="password">password</label>
                <input  className="form-input"
                type="password" 
                value={password} 
                name="password"
                autoComplete="off"
                onChange={this.handleChange} />


                    <button className="button" type="submit">Submit</button>


            </form>
        </div>;
    }
}

export default connect
(
    () => ({}),
    {authUser, logout}
)(Auth);
```